# Block form send email to recipients from a view

Tags: views, forms, blocks, emails

We have a view which can be filtered.
We need a block which can be used to send a message with the recipients coming from the view.
Ideally this would be on the same page.
This would be used by anonymous users so the interface needs to be simple.
We have tried views send but the form is too complex to present to anonymous users.

Possibly an entity form where we can define the fields, user selects the recipients from the view, fills the simple block form and send.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Send](https://drupal.org/project/views_send) module for that.

> Views Send enables you to send mass mailing from a View.

Comment: Thanks. We have tried that but the form is too complex. I should have added that it would be used by anonymous users and needs a simple form i.e name, subject, message

Comment: Please edit your question and update with this information that you already tried Views Send module and why it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Contact Form](https://drupal.org/project/views_contact_form) module

> A new Views style which display a contact form, in a block, a page or
>   an attachment. Recipients are taken from a field you define.

Comment: Is there a way to add checkbox to the view for views contact form or only send to all listed in the view?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean

Comment: I have a view page setup with a views contact form on the side. It sends the form to each result in the view. Is there a way to add a checkbox like vbo to the view so the user can select the recipients then send the form

Answer (score 0):

Add the "Send email" field to your Fields list